# Swift - Crash when UIButton.addTarget in init()

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

```
class Test: NSObject {

init(mainView:UIView){
   super.init()
   var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
   button.setTitle("Test", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
   button.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
   button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 40)
   button.addTarget(self, action: "doSomething", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
   mainView.addSubview(button)
}
func doSomething(){
   println("test")
}
}
```

in other class I try to doSomething() by clicking this button, but unsuccessfully my app crash...

```
var testvar = Test(view)
```

How to trigger this function by button pressed without app crash ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a memory management issue. Your problem is that the `Test` instance you stored in the local variable `testvar` will be released after you left the method. The `addTarget` of UIButton method does not retain it's target, so there are no more strong references to the `Test` instance and it will be deallocated. If you tap the button the system tries to call `doSomething` on the now deallocated instance. Which leads to a crash.

You could store the instance in a instance variable of your UIViewController (or whatever object calls `var testvar =`).

e.g.:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    var testvar: Test!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        testvar = Test(mainView:self.view)
    }
}
```